# A question related to java functions and usage of different methods of strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, function, arraylist

I hope everyone are doing fine....I have one very much complicated doubt in java, in function palindrome I used the function compareTo function to test that my program is working fine or not and also I used equals function before, which was returning me false even if two strings were perfectly fine to test it I used toCompare function which should return me 0 if the string is palindrome but it is not returning me zero instead it is giving me 87 and 77 respectively for both MOM and WOW respectively, please anyone help me by solving this doubt..pleaseeeeee....[image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HYek.jpg) [image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v02TI.png)

```
import java.util.*;
public class functions{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str;
    char[] ch = new char[20];
    System.out.println("Enter the String");
    str=s.nextLine();
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
    {
        ch[i] = str.charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.println("String before reversal :"+str);
    reverseString(ch);
    String str1=String.valueOf(ch);
    System.out.println("String after reversal :"+str1);
    /*if(isPalindrome(ch))
    {
        System.out.println("String is a Palindrome");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("String is not a Palindrome");
    }*/
    boolean test = isPalindrome(ch);
    System.out.println(test);

}
public static void reverseString(char[] ch)
{
    String str= String.valueOf(ch);
    int j=0;
    for(int i=str.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        ch[j]=str.charAt(i);
        j++;
    }

}
public static boolean isPalindrome(char[] ch)
{
    String str=String.valueOf(ch);
    reverseString(ch);
    String str1=String.valueOf(ch);
    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.println(str1);
    System.out.println(str1.compareTo(str));
    if(str.equalsIgnoreCase(str1)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: yes I have changed that thing 

Comment: This code doesn't use `toCompare`. Do you mean `compareTo`? It's not relevant that it returns 86 or 87: `compareTo` returns a negative, zero or positive; the actual values (other than zero) are irrelevant.

Comment: Your reverse code is wrong. Also creating a String from a char array with unset indices doesn't magically erase them, they are still there and still used.

Answer (score 1):

Your Problem is that you create an array with a fixed length of 20. So when you put "WOW" in that there will still be 17 parts of that array filled with the char default value '\u0000'.

That is because the method `String.valueOf(char data[])` will simply copy the passed char array and use that copy as its backing array.

While that may not make a difference for printing the String it leads to reversed String not being considered equal to the original String, because one has a backing array that starts with 17 `'\u0000'` values and ends with `'W', 'O', 'W'` while the other one starts with `'W', 'O', 'W'` and ends with 17 `'\u0000'` values.

To fix that simply declare your char array with a dynamic length of the read in string after you the user entered it:

```
System.out.println("Enter the String");
str = s.nextLine();
char[] ch = new char[str.length()];
```

Comment: Thank you too much.....you explained it very well 

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String theString) {
    
    String reverse = new StringBuilder(theString).reverse().toString();
    boolean result = false;
    if(theString.equalsIgnoreCase(reverse)) {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

... or were you wondering about why your solution did not work as expected? My apologies then. That was well explained by others :)